# Rider Reformat How to adjust the white line?

Tags: rider

[How to adjust the white line?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nx7M9.png)

When one line of code crosses the white line, it moves to the next line. Is there any way to change the white color line?

Comment: look for any settings that refer to `line wrap`

Comment: Thank you bro, solved the problem. Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> General -> Hard wrap at -> value edit

Comment: If that is about rider then why is it tagged with `VisualStudio` and `VisualStudioCode` which are two completely different IDEs?